# Is there any difference in changing NetBeans default JFrame main function?

Tags: java, swing, object, netbeans, jframe

I am quite inexperienced in Java GUI so I am using the NetBeans designer for most of my needs. This is the `main` function that NetBeans generates:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyClass().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
```

I there any substantial difference if I change it to this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    MyClass gui = new MyClass();
                    gui.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        }
```

or even this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass gui = new MyClass();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

I am asking because I am having some problems with some member variables I created which I need to use them in the main function and it won't let me and I also do not understand the `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {` part.

Comment: I think you need to read up on [class members and static variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Once you understand static variables, you'll understand why you can't access some variables in the `main` method.

Comment: @peeskillet I do understand why it does not let me use them in my main method that is why I pursued a way in creating the `MyClass` object properly and calling the methods I need from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and second option are quite the same, the third is rather risky. Point about invokeLater is to put GUI objects into event loop that is waiting for actions. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

The first two code snippets are strictly equivalent. The third one is not, at all: you are supposed to interact with all Swing graphical elements (apart from a few exceptions) from [the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Your last example creates and shows a JFrame outside the EDT: that may behave unexpectedly.